# What is the algebraic notation for the bishop?

Tags: notation

Let's say that I have a pawn at b2 and a bishop at d2 and I want to capture the pawn on c3 with my bishop. The expression I used is bc3. However, it uses my pawn at b2 to capture the pawn at c3. I then tried b2c3, but it did the same.

How do you use bishop to capture the pawn at c3 with algebraic expression in this case?

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/8/8/8/2p5/PP1BPPPP/RN1QKBNR w KQkq - 0 4"]

1.Bxc3 (1.bxc3)
```

Comment: @mateenulhaq your edit makes the question contain its own answer :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The expression I used is bc3

Lowercase letters **ALWAYS** refer to pawns/files. Uppercase **ALWAYS** refers to pieces. You need to use Bxc3 for "Bishop at d2"xc3.

Comment: "Lowercase letters ALWAYS refer to pawns/files. Uppercase ALWAYS refers to pieces." Well, not exactly. "x" is a lowercase letter that always refers to a capture. O is an uppercase letter that always refers to part of a castling manoeuvre.